504.0 GatewayTimeout when deploying to Azure WebApp
I am currently trying to deploy a Zip file to an Azure WebApp. The Zip file is created by Doxygen and has a size of 19MB. The clean flag is set to false because each of my pipeline build created a zip which should be hosted on a different path within that WebApp.
I am getting a 504 Gateway error whenever I try to deploy with the false flag. With the flag set to true it works but also not everytime.
As suggested here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/474028/deploying-to-azure-app-services-causes-timeout-(er](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/474028/deploying-to-azure-app-services-causes-timeout-(er) I have set
WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false

My pipe looks like this:
- task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Set Application Settings'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'serviceconnection'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                az webapp config appsettings set \
                  --resource-group 'rg-xxx' \
                  --name 'app-xxx' \
                  --settings WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE=false

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'serviceconnection'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                az webapp deploy \
                  --resource-group 'rg-xxx' \
                  --name 'app-xxx' \
                  --src-path $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/html.zip \
                  --type zip \
                  --clean false \
                  --target-path $(varSourceBranchName)


What could I do to resolve this issue. I am grateful for any suggestions/input.
Thank you


I am getting a 504 Gateway error whenever I try to deploy with the false flag. With the flag set to true it works but also not everytime.

You'll most likely find that the success rate will be similar at a given time regardless of the clean setting.
The 504.0 Bad Gateway is coming from the App Service load balancer. The load balancer is part of the platform, and is responsible for routing requests to the various running app instances, including the Site Control Manager application (SCM).
SCM shares the same resources as your application. The load balancer will give you a 504 when SCM doesn't respond within 230 seconds.
The reason SCM is not responding is most likely due to resource contention in your app service instance. It may be low on memory, or the CPU may be overloaded, causing the SCM instance to take longer than 230 seconds to start up.
To resolve this issue you should either troubleshoot the resource usage, looking for memory leaks in applications and inefficient code, or you should scale-up your App Service Plan to a sku or tier which provides adequate resources.

Thank you for your response. I have scaled it up from B1 to B3 tier and I still get the same error. CPU percentage is 6% as avarage and has a peak at 12 % and memory is averaging at 50%. I also have put the app into its own app service so it doesn't share resources with other apps.

Even with a really pricy tier like P2v3 I would still get the same error

Can you browse to https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net?

Yes, I have acces to this page

When I have a look at my deployment logs, it tells me that the deployment has been succesfull but still the page is not accesable and the pipeine would give me 504

@mr_bean where are you getting these logs? Could you inspect and post the logs from site -> wwwroot -> Logs -> zipdeploy?

I am getting thte logs from scm.azurewebsites.net/deploymentlogs/ and the end of the log looks like this: Build completed succesfully.
2024-06-18T08:47:35  Running post deployment command(s)...
2024-06-18T08:47:35  Triggering container recycle for OneDeploy by adding/updating restartTrigger.txt to the site root path
2024-06-18T08:47:36  Deployment successful. deployer = OneDeploy deploymentPath = OneDeploy

@mr_bean Those logs are produced by a different task to that which you posted. OneDeploy is integrated in to DevOps for delta deployments, and doesn't support extracting zip files. az webapp deploy ... --type zip ... uses ZipDeploy. Take a look in the directory I provided through the SCM/Kudu interface and see if you have logs in there. Do you have any other tasks in your pipeline which could be deploying the app in addition to your az webapp deploy task?

No I there are no other deployments taking place. But the log are the ones from my attempted deployment. I haven't posted the whole log because of character retstriction but in the first lines it states that it is deploying with zip. 2024-06-18T08:41:25    Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/b141522f-d9db-4f4c-87f4-7d55791c72f1.zip (18.27 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2024-06-18T08:41:36  Updating submodules.
2024-06-18T08:41:36  Preparing deployment for commit id '12fa49bc-6'.

This cannot be an answer, what is the solution here. How can we use this technique to deploy our application to Appservice

Things to look at in the logs (for a failed deployment) are timings of each activity taken place during deployment. If, from start to end, your deployment reaches 230 seconds, then you need to find the culprit activity which will guide to the underlying issue. Your gateway error could only be one of two things...an Azure App Service issue (raise with support), or a timeout (230 seconds) in completing its activity.

@mr_bean - did you ever find a resolution to this?

sorry for my late respose. Unfortunately, I couldnt fix this issue

Azure is such a horrible system, struggling with this since days now
