Azure AppService with Django on Linux using Azure Devops for CI takes 20 minutes
I am using Django on Linux with Azure Devops as Continuous Integration / Continuous Development purposes.
I have succesfully setup the yaml file for deployment and associated with Azure AppService which seems to be working ok.
However it takes a long time ( about 20 minutes ), it was a lot faster with other cloud providers ( such as 3-4 minutes )
Here below is my azure-pipelines-prod.yaml file :
# Python to Linux Web App on Azure
# Build your Python project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux Web App.
# Change python version to one thats appropriate for your application.
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- main

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'xxxxxxxx-7f93-4dc6-922b-ae9b29311fbf'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'project-app'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'project-app'

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  pythonVersion: '3.9'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install --target="./antenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages" -r ./requirements-azure.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : project-app'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip

And here below is my AppService environment settings :
[
  {
    "name": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
    "value": "xxxxxxx-790e-4de9-9efe-60f046024752",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "value": "XXXXXXXXX~9ezzAV2qI5uDVx8Khc7CMCDXf5mfICFbQN",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "DISABLE_PHP_BUILD",
    "value": "false",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "PORT",
    "value": "8000",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "3",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT",
    "value": "1000",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_PORT",
    "value": "8000",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
    "value": "default",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  }
]

Whenever I make a commit to the main branch that is defined in azure-pipeline-prod, it triggers a build, and the build zip is then loaded onto AppService. However, it is really very slow, and consumes monthly 1800 parallel build minutes that is granted by Azure Subscription. The zip file is about 1Mbyte and the artifact with all django packages is about 170 Mbytes as seen below :
Physical Content Uploaded: 147.7 MB
Logical Content Uploaded: 154.9 MB
Compression Saved: 7.2 MB
Deduplication Saved: 181.2 MB
Number of Chunks Uploaded: 127
Total Number of Chunks: 409

I am open to any suggestions, in order to make it more stable (the build sometimes fails) and a lot more faster.
Update :
The build / deploy procedure stays on this following step and logs about 16 minutes :
Deploy Azure Web App : project-app
##[debug][GET]https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z
##[debug]POLL URL RESULT: {"statusCode":202,"statusMessage":"Accepted","headers":{"content-length":"825","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:08:44 GMT","server":"Kestrel","location":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":1,"status_text":"Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"Running deployment command...","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":null,"last_success_end_time":null,"complete":false,"active":false,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]Deployment status: 1 'Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.'. retry after 5 seconds
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 22269.41 MB out of 74244.74 MB, Memory: Used 1120.00 MB out of 6930.00 MB, CPU: Usage 1.48%
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]CLIENT_RESETSTREAMONRETRY=undefined
##[debug][GET]https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z
##[debug]POLL URL RESULT: {"statusCode":202,"statusMessage":"Accepted","headers":{"content-length":"825","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:08:50 GMT","server":"Kestrel","location":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":1,"status_text":"Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"Running deployment command...","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":null,"last_success_end_time":null,"complete":false,"active":false,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]Deployment status: 1 'Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.'. retry after 5 seconds
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 22269.41 MB out of 74244.74 MB, Memory: Used 1120.00 MB out of 6930.00 MB, CPU: Usage 0.48%
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]CLIENT_RESETSTREAMONRETRY=undefined
##[debug][GET]https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z
##[debug]POLL URL RESULT: {"statusCode":202,"statusMessage":"Accepted","headers":{"content-length":"825","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:08:56 GMT","server":"Kestrel","location":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":1,"status_text":"Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"Running deployment command...","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":null,"last_success_end_time":null,"complete":false,"active":false,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]Deployment status: 1 'Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.'. retry after 5 seconds
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 22269.41 MB out of 74244.74 MB, Memory: Used 1120.00 MB out of 6930.00 MB, CPU: Usage 0.95%
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]CLIENT_RESETSTREAMONRETRY=undefined
##[debug][GET]https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 22269.41 MB out of 74244.74 MB, Memory: Used 1120.00 MB out of 6930.00 MB, CPU: Usage 13.98%
##[debug]POLL URL RESULT: {"statusCode":202,"statusMessage":"Accepted","headers":{"content-length":"825","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:09:01 GMT","server":"Kestrel","location":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":1,"status_text":"Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"Running deployment command...","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":null,"last_success_end_time":null,"complete":false,"active":false,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]Deployment status: 1 'Building and Deploying '76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2'.'. retry after 5 seconds
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]CLIENT_RESETSTREAMONRETRY=undefined
##[debug][GET]https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY&time=2024-09-21_13-51-54Z
##[debug]POLL URL RESULT: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"content-length":"784","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:09:07 GMT","server":"Kestrel"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":4,"status_text":"","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":"2024-09-21T14:09:04.7067259Z","last_success_end_time":"2024-09-21T14:09:04.7067259Z","complete":true,"active":true,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=4171aae28232215c7c1d6de5a1f7b3cadffd5db6661afdb90cc5cdd8c510f819;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug]CLIENT_RESETSTREAMONRETRY=undefined
##[debug][GET]https://***:***@project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2
##[debug]getDeploymentDetails. Data: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"content-length":"784","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 21 Sep 2024 14:09:07 GMT","server":"Kestrel"},"body":{"id":"76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","status":4,"status_text":"","author_email":"N/A","author":"N/A","deployer":"VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY","message":"Created via a push deployment","progress":"","received_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:11.1812709Z","start_time":"2024-09-21T13:52:12.4271044Z","end_time":"2024-09-21T14:09:04.7067259Z","last_success_end_time":"2024-09-21T14:09:04.7067259Z","complete":true,"active":true,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":true,"url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2","log_url":"https://project-app-g3esbuddfgcfhjgg.scm.uksouth-01.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/76d0215b-28d3-4460-ad39-c22b2b45dbd2/log","site_name":"project-app","build_summary":{"errors":[],"warnings":[]}}}
##[debug]system.debug=True


Update after setting to true as AppService Environment Variable :
I am now facing this error SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true :

After setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true, I can manually upload the application via az cli, it seems like it is deployed fine, however I dont see any updated information on Deployment Center Logs :
% az webapp deploy \
  --resource-group project-app-development_group \
  --name project-app \
  --src-path project-app.zip
Deployment type: zip. To override deployment type, please specify the --type parameter. Possible values: war, jar, ear, zip, startup, script, static
Initiating deployment
Deploying from local path: project-app.zip
Polling the status of sync deployment. Start Time: 2024-10-03 21:45:15.290074+00:00 UTC
Status: Build successful. Time: 0(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 16(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 31(s)
Status: Site started successfully. Time: 47(s)
Deployment has completed successfully
You can visit your app at: https://api.project.uk
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/da075a40-b7b2-4bef-a2f2-e27c84121641/resourceGroups/project-app-development_group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/project-app/deploymentStatus/XXXXXXXXX-2f41-4ad8-b284-bc1387bbdcbc",
  "location": "UK South",
  "name": "XXXXXX-2f41-4ad8-b284-bc1387bbdcbc",
  "properties": {
    "deploymentId": "XXXXXX-2f41-4ad8-b284-bc1387bbdcbc",
    "errors": null,
    "failedInstancesLogs": null,
    "numberOfInstancesFailed": 0,
    "numberOfInstancesInProgress": 0,
    "numberOfInstancesSuccessful": 1,
    "status": "RuntimeSuccessful"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "project-app-development_group",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-link: /app-insights-conn-string": "InstrumentationKey=dd0efcf1-efc2-4d69-97ab-41e01d18ef10;IngestionEndpoint=https://uksouth-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://uksouth.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=d195e35e-1721-4093-9fcd-e7ebdedda6fd",
    "hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key": "dd0efcf1-efc2-4d69-97ab-41e01d18ef10",
    "hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-b7b2-4bef-a2f2-e27c84121641/resourceGroups/project-app-development_group/providers/microsoft.insights/components/project-app202409211017"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/deploymentStatus"
}

Here you can find the 504 Gateway timeout error as well when AzureCLI2 is used :


What are the slowest steps from the logs?

I have updated with the logs where it stays about 16 minutes.

I have also added a screenshot of the whole duration information for each step in azure devops build situation.

@LexLi, can you please have a look at latest logs? I have set this "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" and now I can use azure cli to upload te app manually, however, now Azure Devops deployment is failing all the time.

According to the documents to Run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package and Enable build automation,

Run from package is not supported for Python apps. When deploying a ZIP file of your Python code, you need to set a flag to enable Azure build automation. The build automation will create the Python virtual environment for your app and install any necessary requirements and package needed.


When deploying a ZIP file of your Python code, you need to set a flag to enable Azure build automation. The build automation will install any necessary requirements and package the application to run on Azure.
Build automation in Azure is enabled by setting the SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT app setting in either the Azure portal or Azure CLI.


As far as I tested, my deployment failed via az webapp deploy --name $APP_SERVICE_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --type zip --src-path "local.zip" command and pipeline deployment incurred similar issues to take more time than usual, until
I set the environment variable SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT as true in the app settings.
To verify and narrow down/rule out possible root causes of the issue, you may also run the Azure CLI command az webapp deploy --name $APP_SERVICE_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --type zip --src-path "local.zip" through Azure CloudShell or local PowerShell to deploy the same artifact zip file, before integrating the deployment in pipelines.
You may also use the two pipeline tasks for a test.
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: '$(azureServiceConnectionId)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    # StartupCommand: 'startup.txt'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureServiceConnectionId)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az webapp deploy \
      --resource-group project-app-development_group \
      --name $(webAppName) \
      --src-path $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip --debug


Alright, but what shall I do here ? In a sentence please ?

@london_utku, As stated, set the environment variable SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT as true in the app settings and try again. If the issue persists, run az webapp deploy --name $APP_SERVICE_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --type zip --src-path "local.zip" to double check the deployment behavior without using pipelines for isolating the cause of the issue.

@london_utku, How is the issue going with SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT set as true in your app settings? Does deployment via az webapp deploy incurs the same issue?

@alvin-zhao-msft, I have updated the ticket with suggested SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT - true AppService variable. Now it is consistently not building at all.

Also when I add this flag SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT, the logs says that the app is updated, however, I am putting some indicators to check if the code is updated, but it is not making any impact.

I can now see the app is updated correctly when az cli is used.

So you deployment via az webapp deploy succeeded with SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT setting but failed in pipeline deployment? If possible you may have a test with the AzureCLI@2 or AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 task.

Where shall I exactly add AzureCLI@2 & AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 in the yaml file ? Is there anything else that I am supposed to remove. It would be excellent if you provide the newly suggested yaml as whole.

I used this AzureCLI@2, it timed out in 230 seconds just as exactly here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78634335/504-0-gatewaytimeout-when-deploying-to-azure-webapp, Then I tried this AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4, it worked but again in about 20 minutes.

You can use either AzureCLI@2  or AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 to replace AzureWebApp@1 task. Do you mean you ran the same command in pipelines as that worked locally? Did you also set WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false as described in the link you shared?

Yes, I have set this WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false. Nothing has changed AzureCLI@2  is failing with" ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: An error occurred during deployment. Status Code: 504, Details: 504.0 GatewayTimeout, Please visit https://project to get more information about your deployment" and AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 is still taking 20 minutes.

May I ask why you set WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false? And when you set it as false, you local AzureCLI command still worked? In my site it was set as true and my deployment via AzureCLI or AzureWebApp@1 all worked.

Because you said this in your previous comment 2 hours ago.

When I set WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false, Nothing has changed AzureCLI@2 is failing with" ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: An error occurred during deployment. Status Code: 504, Details: 504.0 GatewayTimeout, Please visit project to get more information about your deployment" and AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 is still taking 20 minutes.

I never suggested you set WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false. I asked if you also set WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false as described in the link you shared.

I have both tried with WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = false or WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = true or WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE not defined in AppService, Nothing has changed AzureCLI@2 is failing with" ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: An error occurred during deployment. Status Code: 504, Details: 504.0 GatewayTimeout, Please visit project to get more information about your deployment" and AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 is still taking 20 minutes.

Why there is 230 seconds limitation for SCM ? That is causing the deployment to fail when AzureCLI@2 is failing with" ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: An error occurred during deployment. Status Code: 504, Details: 504.0 GatewayTimeout,

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You mentioned that I can now see the app is updated correctly when az cli is used. I don't quite understand why the same az cli command to deploy app package could incur 504 errors during deployment. What was changed after your app was updated correctly via az cli deployment? You can share the information in your original post rather than in the discussions to engage insights from the community.

Nothing is changed in the application. With az cli only update, it works perfectly. When it is processing through Azure Pipeline,  this is exactly what happens : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78634335/504-0-gatewaytimeout-when-deploying-to-azure-webapp

You can share the latest definition with AzureCLI@2 task to engage the insights from the community experts. Theologically, the same az cli command to deploy the same package should work as well, no matter where the command was executed.

SCM simply timeouts after 230 seconds, and it is unconfigurable, it is clearly mentioned on this ticket from Microsoft colleagues, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78634335/504-0-gatewaytimeout-when-deploying-to-azure-webapp . What shall we do on this case ...

That post used another task to set webapp configurations, which was not included in your original post. Are you deploying the same artifacts as that app did? As mentioned, the same az cli command to deploy the same package should work as well, no matter where the command was executed.
